# Understanding "en vomissaient" in Mademoiselle Fifi

Tags: sens, pronoms, verbes

What is the grammatical account of *en vomissaient* in this passage from Maupassant's 1882 story Mademoiselle Fifi?

I assume the context is the war of 1870.  Five Prussian officers have requisitioned some tavern women for a makeshift soirée.

> On s’assit. Le commandant lui-même semblait enchanté ; il prit à sa droite Paméla, Blondine à sa gauche, et déclara, en dépliant sa serviette : « Vous avez eu là une charmante idée, capitaine. »
>        Les lieutenants Otto et Fritz, polis comme auprès de femmes du monde, intimidaient un peu leurs voisines ; mais le baron de Kelweingstein, lâché dans son vice, rayonnait, lançait des mots grivois, semblait en feu avec sa couronne de cheveux rouges. Il galantisait en français du Rhin ; et ses compliments de taverne, expectorés par le trou des deux dents brisées, arrivaient aux filles au milieu d’une mitraille de salive.
>        Elles ne comprenaient rien, du reste ; et leur intelligence ne sembla s’éveiller que lorsqu’il cracha des paroles obscènes, des expressions crues, estropiées par son accent. Alors, toutes ensemble, elles commencèrent à rire comme des folles, tombant sur le ventre de leurs voisins, répétant les termes que le baron se mit alors à défigurer à plaisir pour leur faire dire des ordures. Elles **en vomissaient** à volonté, saoules aux premières bouteilles de vin ; et, redevenant elles, ouvrant la porte aux habitudes, elles embrassaient les moustaches de droite et celles de gauche, pinçaient les bras, poussaient des cris furieux, buvaient dans tous les verres, chantaient des couplets français et des bouts de chansons allemandes appris dans leurs rapports quotidiens avec l’ennemi.

By grammatical account I mean things like these.

1. *vomissaient* is here intransitive; *en* stands for *de ordures* (or maybe *des ordures* for *de* + *les ordures*), which complements the verb.  That is to say, I should understand it on the model of the expressions highlighted below in this other excerpt from the same story.

> Sur les murs, trois portraits de famille, un guerrier vêtu de fer, un cardinal et un président, fumaient **de longues pipes de porcelaine**, tandis qu’en son cadre dédoré par les ans, une noble dame à poitrine serrée montrait **d’un air arrogant** une énorme paire de moustaches faite au charbon.

2. *vomissaient* is here transitive and takes *en* for a direct object.  (I don't know that *en* can ever be a direct object.)
3. *en vomir* is a single expression not be further analyzed, as with *s'en aller*.

I find that *en* is one of the three trickiest words in French, the others being *de* and *que*.  I am trying to understand it as completely as I can whenever I see it.  Thanks.

Comment: In *de longues pipes*, *de* is an article (shortened *des* in front of an adjective). In this example *en* isn't a pronoun. It's a preposition. The second highlighted *de* is a preposition which isn't bound to the verb. It introduces an adverbial group.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez I do not understand *de longues pipes de porcelaines* to be the subject of *fumaient* but its object, the subject being in that case *trois portraits de famille*, i.e. the warrior, the cardinal and the president.

Comment: @jlliagre: Ah sorry, my bad. You're right. I read too quickly.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez. *de longues pipes*: I am so used to English plural nouns not needing an indefinite article that immediately I thought it meant "smoking *of* long pipes." / *d’un air arrogant*: Yes I meant an adverbial phrase that modifies *montrait*. Maybe "complement" is not the right word. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's your second guess. *Elles en vomissaient* means *elles vomissaient des ordures* (i.e. *des mots orduriers*.)

In the tlfi [en (pronoun) entry](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/en/1):

> I.− [L'antécédent est explicite et de nature nom.]
>
> A.− [L'antécédent est un subst., un adv. ou un pron.]
>
> 1. [L'antécédent est représenté sans être à son tour déterminé]
>
> b) [En corresp. à l'art. partitif de le, du...]  … On voyait cette année-là
> dans les vitrines d'absurdes jupons longs et soyeux : **j'en achetai**
> (Beauvoir, Mandarins,1954, p. 509)